# CapsLock, NumLock, Insert, how to show keyboard status on screen when keyboard has no LED

Tags: linux, keyboard

When keyboard has **no LED**, for Linux machine, is there an easy way to do this? By Command Line, Python, Perl or Ruby, to show when keyboard has `CapLock`, `NumLock` activated?

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: Could be extracted to Super User... not sure if that still happens now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [post](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/key-mon-displays-keyboard-and-mouse.html) about the *key-mon* tool.

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/key-mon-displays-keyboard-and-mouse.html

As far as I know there is also a CLI command to check the status in the package.

Comment: _Actually_ not everyone has/wants gnome ... common Ubuntu desktops include: gnome, kde, fce, cinnamon, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the command line to check led status use:

```
xset q | grep LED
```

This will return a number resulting from the binary addition of the led status lights. Caps lock is the first bit, Numlock is the second... the rest you need to experiment as I have only used those two.

Comment: Sometimes it is handy to us `less` for this kind of situation, because you never know what _else_ may be useful when poking about in settings and options.  For example; try, `xset q | less -p LED` ... I will show you the first line with  "LED" and also _all_ the settings/output :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gnome 3 [Lock Keys](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/) extension may be useful.

Comment: However, it doesn't work when on the login and unlock screens.  I opened an issue for that at https://github.com/kazysmaster/gnome-shell-extension-lockkeys/issues/52.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, also applies if you have a virtual machine.

I found the following code worked well on my Ubuntu lucid VM running on ESXi 5.1 with no hardware LEDs on a mx5500 revolution Bluetooth keyboard combo.

http://freecode.com/projects/numlockx

```
tar -xzf numlockx-1.2.tar.gz
./configure
make
./numlockx on
```

You may not be able to see the current state, but at least you can force it to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple language input-sources installed, you'll likely have a language switching menu in the top-right corner (i.e. [ en | fr ]). Its context menu has an option "Show Keyboard Layout" which has its own virtual LED indicator.

However, it only stays in sync if that window has the focus. If you e.g. toggle numlock in gedit but keep this window open in the background, you'll see that it keeps its old state.