# Detecting a NUMLOCK / CAPSLOCK / SCRLOCK keypress/keyup in Python

Tags: python, keyboard, curses, num-lock

In a game I'm developing, I want to detect a `NUMLOCK` ***keypress*** (or *keyup*), like registering a "callback" function when it gets pressed.

I'm not asking to read its *state* in a given moment, [I can do that already](https://github.com/MestreLion/pyrogue/blob/master/pyrogue/input.py), nor I'm interested in changing its value. It's about being aware of the keypress *when it happens* so I don't have to poll its state every tenth of a sec or so.

The game uses `curses`, and currently a blocking `getch()`. Curses does not detect `NUMLOCK` keypresses, and I never expected it to (led-related keyboard don't "produce" any key), and I wonder if there is any way to do so that is better than than replacing the main curses loop with a non-blocking `getch()` and call a `keyboard_leds()` function to read current state.

For example: I could start a new thread after initializing curses, passing its `stdscr` screen as argument, and that thread would register register a callback function (say, `special_keypress()`) for the event of a `NUMLOCK` keypress. Thus, that function would only invoke `keyboard_leds()` when needed, and then update `stdscr`.

I'm not sure if this is possible, and I'm aware that I'll probably have to go down to some architecture-dependent stuff (kernel/X11, etc), so if a cross-platform solution is not possible, then I'm fine with a Linux-only one.

Comment: Probable dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054681/capslock-numlock-insert-how-to-show-keyboard-status-on-screen-when-keyboard-h

Comment: @MarcB: They are *related*, but I think very far from *duplicate*. He wants an app to run as daemon to show status in his DE. It is not even a programming question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it's like using a steam-hammer to crack nuts (especially if you are creating a CLI rogue-like game), but Pyglet gets the at least NUMLOCK keypresses in OS X. I couldn't make it work with either `CAPSLOCK` or `SCROLLLOCK` though, but my system hotkeys are pretty much overriden in every way possible, so it may be just me.

You could try and test if it works better for you, and then look at how Pyglet detects these keys.

```
import pyglet

from pyglet.window import key


window = pyglet.window.Window()


@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.NUMLOCK:
        print 'NumLock was pressed, yay!'
    elif symbol == key.CAPSLOCK:
        print 'CapsLock was pressed, yay!'
    elif symbol == key.SCROLLLOCK:
        print 'ScrollLock was pressed, yay!'


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Yeah, `pyglet` is a huge hammer for that nut. I cannot afford to create a window just for led status. It' CLI indeed, `X` might not even be running! :) But thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: @MestreLion No problem, I'm digging further to find a better way. I guess the regular LED polling isn't that bad after all. It shouldn't take a lot of CPU usage.

Comment: That's my backup plan. SO is a shot in the dark to see if there are better alternatives.

Comment: By the way... I'm not creating a "CLI rogue-like", I'm re-creating the _original_ Rogue in Python ;-)